# Elasticsearch NEST client library

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

What we are trying to do is to index a bunch of documents in batches i.e.

```
foreach (var batch in props.ChunkBy(100))
{    

    var result = await client.IndexManyAsync<Type>(batch, indexName);

}
```

We would like to **STOP** Elasticsearch **REFRESHING** the Index until we have finished indexing all the batches. Then enable and refresh the index.

How can we achieve this with the NEST library

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can effectively disable the index refresh by setting the interval value to -1. Below is a code sample that shows how to set the refresh interval to -1 using the Nest client. Then you can do your bulk operations and afterwards set the refresh interval back to the default of 1 second.

```cs
//Set Index Refresh Interval to -1, essentially disabling the refresh
var updateDisableIndexRefresh = new UpdateIndexSettingsRequest();
updateDisableIndexRefresh.IndexSettings.RefreshInterval = Time.MinusOne;
client.UpdateIndexSettings(updateDisableIndexRefresh);

//Do your bulk operations here...

//Reset the Index Refresh Interval back to 1 second, the default setting.
var updateEnableIndexRefresh = new UpdateIndexSettingsRequest();
updateEnableIndexRefresh.IndexSettings.RefreshInterval = new Time(1, TimeUnit.Second);
client.UpdateIndexSettings(updateEnableIndexRefresh);
```